# Java 8 stream grouping by within an Object containing list of String

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am not so familiar with Java 8 (still learning) and looking to see if I could find something equivalent of the below code using streams.

The below code mainly tries to get tag for each person and then groups them based on this Tag. One person can be associated with Multiple tags - Please let me know if this is a duplicate :(
I was not able to find solution for it online.

The part I want to simplify
Safe assumption - No null checks required

```
Map<Tag, List<String>> tagPersonListMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Person person: personList) {
    List<Tag> tags = person.getTags();
    String id = person.getId();
    for(Tag tag: tags) {
        tagPersonListMap.computeIfAbsent(tag, k ->new ArrayList<>()).add(id);
    }
}
```

Entire code for reference

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person(Arrays.asList(Tag.EMPLOYEE, Tag.UNKNOWN), "123");
        Person person2 = new Person(Arrays.asList(Tag.UNKNOWN, Tag.VISITOR), "345");
        Person person3 = new Person(Arrays.asList(Tag.VISITOR), "678");
        Person person4 = new Person(Arrays.asList(Tag.EMPLOYEE, Tag.UNKNOWN), "910");
        List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
            person1, person2,
            person3, person4
        );

        Map<Tag, List<String>> tagPersonListMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Person person: personList) {
            List<Tag> tags = person.getTags();
            String id = person.getId();
            for(Tag tag: tags) {
                tagPersonListMap.computeIfAbsent(tag, k ->new ArrayList<>()).add(id);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Final result: " + tagPersonListMap);
    }
}

enum Tag {
    EMPLOYEE("employee"),
    VISITOR("visitor"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown");
    private final String mValue;
    private Tag(String value) {
        this.mValue = value;
    }
}

class Person {
    List<Tag> tags;
    String id;

    Person (List<Tag> tag, String i) {
        tags = tag;
        id = i;
    }

    List<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
Final result: {EMPLOYEE=[123, 910], UNKNOWN=[123, 345, 910], VISITOR=[345, 678]}
```

Comment: AFAICT there is nothing in Java 8 that will do this. Your code looks fine as it is btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.  To achieve this I essentially converted the tag list and the id to `Map.Entry` objects of `(Tag tag, String id)`.   So if there were four tags and one Id that would be four entries.  Then I simply grouped them by `Tag` with a value of `List<String>`.

```
Map<Tag, List<String>> result = personList.stream()
        .flatMap(per -> per.getTags().stream()
                .map(tag -> Map.entry(tag, per.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue,
                                Collectors.toList())));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
UNKNOWN=[123, 345, 910]
EMPLOYEE=[123, 910]
VISITOR=[345, 678]
```

Having done this I would still stick with what you have.  Sometimes, using streams is like driving a nail with a sledge hammer.

Comment: yup - seems like streams would complicate it over simplifying it :( 

Thats what I was afraid of. Thanks for giving it try though :D